# visual studio code debug console write strange result

Tags: visual-studio-code, cygwin, fork

Fork program works in Linux, but in cygwin produce unexpected result.
This is the program

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main(){
int pid; /* process identifier */
    printf("Start\n");
    pid=fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {printf("Cannot fork!!\n");
         exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {/* child process */ 
        printf("Child\n");
    }
    else 
    {/* parent process pid is child's pid */ 
        printf("Parent\n");
    }
}
```

Expected result (in Linux works):

```
Start
Child
Parent
```

Obtained result (cygwin on Windows 10):

```
Start
Child
[New Thread 860.0x3204]
Start
Parent
```

starting the .exe from windows cmd produces the correct output but starting from Visual studio code produce the start print 2 times on visual studio debug console.

any ideas?

Comment: Both of your results seem strange. On my cygwin and Ubuntu, I have `Start Parent Child`

Comment: this "Start Parent Child" could be because after a fork there is no guarantee that che child starts after the parent. the strange result is 2 times "start" on cygwin